# Why new FileInputStream return null while in debug object is evaluated

Tags: java, inputstream

I have this code:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new FileURL(fileName));
properties.load(is);
```

And i have this exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null

Walking step by step in debug i see that my 'is' variable is null.
But when i evaluating (ctrl+u in idea)

```
new FileInputStream(new FileURL(fileName));
```

i get normal FileInputStream object asigned to referenced properties file.
Please help.

Comment: Where does your `FileURL` class come from?

Comment: It is custom project class

Comment: it extends java.io.File

Comment: If your code really looks like the above, meaning that the call to `properties.load(is)` is directly following the previous creation of `FileInputStream`, there's no way that `is` is null at that point. The construction of an object can either fail with an exception, or succeed, but will never yield null.

Comment: The analysis of @codeflush.dev is right. I think you should provide more of your code. Also the stack trace of the NullPointerException would help.

Comment: The second line of code follows first immediatelly. But on customer server i found - InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new FileURL(fileName)); replaced with InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName); It explains this debug strange things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
      try 
      {
         File file = new File( fileName ) ;
          if (!file.exists())
           return ;

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream( file ) ;

        try 
        {
          props.load( in ) ;
        } 
        finally 
        {
          in.close() ;
        }
     }  
     catch (Exception exc) 
     {
        if (debug)
        System.out.println( "ORB properties file " + fileName +
            " not found: " + exc) ;
     }
```